# Can we hide and show child checkbox when click on specific parent checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox

I want to display specific child checkbox when click on parent checkbox but the value of checkbox is come from database column

```
 <input name="service[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $service['id']; ?>" id="" />

<?php 
echo $service['servicename'];
echo "<br>";
?>

<br><br>

<?php foreach ($activities as $activity) : ?>

    <input name="activity[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $activity['id']; ?>" />

    <?php 
    echo $activity['nameofactivity'];
    echo "<br>";
```

My Output:

- 1.Incometax
- Return
- Filling
- 2.GST
- Form
- submitform

I want to display Return and Flling [activity of 1 st service] when click on Incometax[1 st service]and display Form and submitform[activity of 2 nd service] when click on [2nd service ]GST. but when click on incometax[1 st service] then hide Form and submitform[activity of second if opens] and when i click on GST[2 nd service] then hide Return and Filling [activity of 1 st service if opens]

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is possible and you will need to use javascript to accomplish it

Comment: But how here is no any different name of checkbox[service] and different name of  checkbox[activity] all the name,id of checkbox is same for all

Comment: design it differently then so that you do have unique identifiers for elements which you can use in code to target whichever element you need.

Comment: can we use value of checkbox for this instead of id because value of checkbox is different

Comment: you can use `querySelector` with the value if you wish... I'd be tempted to start with the database to see if you can set a relationship between records and use that when generating the html content. It would be better though if you were to post more of the pertinent code rather than just snippets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an excuse to get out of the heat I came and put together this little demo of checking/unchecking checkboxes depending upon which parent was ticked. You can copy, save and trun the below to see it in action or try this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/RamRaider/pen/jpGpPK) demo

It makes use of `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` to target child and parent elements within the DOM. I hope this might give an idea how to achieve your goal.

```
<?php
    /*
        dummy data used to generate 
        list with checkboxes and sub-lists...
    */
    $services = array(
        'Incometax'     =>  array(
            'Return',
            'Filling'
        ),
        'GST'           =>  array(
            'Form',
            'submitform'
        )
    );
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Checkboxes...</title>
        <script>
            let _flags={
                capture:false,
                once:false,
                passive:true
            };


            document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded',function( evt ){

                let _form = document.forms.test;
                let _class= 'visible';

                Array.prototype.slice.call( _form.querySelectorAll( 'input[ type="checkbox" ]' ) ).forEach( function( el, i ){

                    if( el.dataset.id ) el.addEventListener( 'click', function( e ){

                        /* Hide all `OL` elements & uncheck  */
                        Array.prototype.slice.call( _form.querySelectorAll( 'li ol' ) ).forEach( function( n ){
                            if( n.classList.contains( _class ) ) {
                                /* Remove the class from child OL element that contains other input elements ( activities ) */
                                n.classList.remove( _class );

                                /* Uncheck the other service checkbox */
                                n.parentNode.querySelector( 'input[ type="checkbox" ]' ).checked=false;

                                /* uncheck all child activity checkboxes */
                                Array.prototype.slice.call( n.querySelectorAll( 'input[ type="checkbox" ]' ) ).forEach( function(chk){
                                    chk.checked=false;
                                } );
                            }
                        } );

                        /* Display relevant activity checkboxes */
                        if( e.target.checked ) e.target.parentNode.querySelector( 'ol' ).classList.toggle( _class );

                    }, _flags );
                });
            }, _flags );
        </script>
        <style>
            ol{display:none;}
            .visible{display:block;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='test'>

            <?php

                $html=array();
                $html[]='<ul>';

                foreach( $services as $service => $activities ){

                    $html[]='<li>';
                    $html[]=sprintf( "<input name='service[]' type='checkbox' data-id='%s' /><label for='%s'>%s</label>", $service, $service, $service );

                    $html[]='<ol>';
                    foreach( $activities as $index => $activity ){
                        $html[]=sprintf( "<li><input type='checkbox' name='activity[]' value='%s' /><label for='%s'>%s</label></li>", $activity, $activity, $activity );
                    }
                    $html[]='</ol>';
                    $html[]='</li>';
                }

                $html[]='</ul>';
                echo implode( PHP_EOL, $html );
            ?>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```